# Finding a specific word in a substitution cipher

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, substitution-cipher

Rand48 is a pseudo-random generator which produces a sequence of any given integer using the following rule:
$a_n=(25214903917 \cdot a_{n-1})\bmod 2^{48}$.

If $b_n=\lfloor a_n/2^{16} \rfloor \bmod 52$, the sequence $b_0, b_1, \dots$ becomes an infinite string called $c=c_0, c_1, \dots$ to the following rule:
$0\to a, 1 \to b, \dots , 25 \to z, 26 \to A, 27 \to B, \dots , 51 \to Z$.

For example, if we choose $a_0=123456$, string $c$ starts with $\mathrm {bQYicNGCY}$.
Correspondingly, if sequence $c$ starts with $\mathrm {EULERcats}$, then $a_0=78580612777175$.

Now, suppose string $c$ starts with $\mathrm {PuzzleOne...}$, what is the index of the first occurrence of the substring $\mathrm {LuckyText}$ in $c$? I think in the first step, we should use the $\mathrm {PuzzleOne...}$ to calculate $a_0$ but I don't know how.

Comment: Your definition is missing the + 11. It should be a_n = (25214903917 * a_n-1 + 11) mod 2^48 to give the results you wrote on the question.